# Automating Firebase and Javascript (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I'm adding users manually as I don't want them to access the app without authorisation.

**Upon adding a user,I would like to add a new child to the database (named from the user email) and send him an email with his logins.**

So far I've arrived to this, that doesn't work (webpack) and I cannot create a child using the current user's email:

```
firebase.auth.user().onCreate(function(event) {
   var uid = event.data.uid;

   return admin.database().ref("/users/" + uid)
});
```

I also found this one for the email:

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate(function(event) {
    var uid = event.data.uid;

    return sendEmail(uid);
});
```

**Do you have any idea what the formula looks like to create a child in the DB with the user and send him an email with his credentials right upon creation of a new user.**